# Bootstrap Drop down menu Works when jQuery file at the bottom of the page, but my other scrips dont work then

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working in Boostrap 3 and the Drop down menu is not working. Or it works, but only when I place the jquery file at the bottom of the page over the bootrsrap.js. The problem is, when I do that the rest of my scipt files don t work, I got waypoints and a custom one. 
I fund a way to trigger the drop down manually but then the collapsed navbar des not expand down when the drop down tabs slide down.
Can anyone help me please.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

<li class="dropdown">

          <a href="#" class ="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img class ="Tab6" src="images/mrkr-sqr.png">LANGUAGE<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"  role="menu">

              <li><a class="language" href="#"><img src="images/mrkr-sqr.png"> ESPANOL</a></li>
              <li><a class="language" href="#"><img src="images/mrkr-sqr.png"> FRANCOIS</a></li>
              <li><a class="language" href="#"><img src="images/mrkr-sqr.png"> PORTUGESE</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
```

Comment: Provide your code and markup, pls.

Comment: Using `jquery-latest` is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Compare what you have to the Bootstrap starter template: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

That's all the help I can really offer without seeing the contents of the file in question.

Comment: Hi. I just uploaded the code. Under that configuration the wayponts and the animate scripts work, but when I move everything to the bottom of the page the drop down works but the scripts stop working.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your header:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
```